# Confused about initialization of SQLite database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

To implement database access in my application I followed [Lars Vogel tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html), but I'm very confused about a couple of things...

The `TodoDbAdapter` class has the following constructor and open method:

```
public TodoDbAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public TodoDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new TodoDatabaseHelper(context);
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

And then this adapter should be initialized like this:

```
dbAdapter = new TodoDbAdapter(this);
dbAdapter.open();
```

**1)** The `getWriteableDatabase` method is the one responsible by throwing a possible `SQLException`. Why do we need to rethrow in our open method? Is there a reason for this?

**2)** What's the point of the whole constructor/open pair? Why not initialize `dbHelper` and get a database ready for writing in the constructor?

**3)** Why do we return the instance of the object in the open method with `return this`? If the open method code were to be moved to the constructor, we no would no longer need to `return this`, it would be implicit, right? What am I missing here?

Comment: Yikes, I had answers written for all the points of your previous big question and then you deleted it seconds before I pushed the button. See below for the first half :)

Comment: Sorry, I was following the other user's suggestion. I'll post the other question in a bit. Or maybe you can edit your answer and I'll edit and add the whole question (I have it saved). Do you want to do that?

Comment: Go ahead with a separate question, the original was really long and deleting it was good. I'll keep watch for your next question.

Comment: For anyone looking for part 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603647/a-few-questions-about-sqlite-database-cursors-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) The `getWriteableDatabase` method is the one responsible by
>   throwing a possible `SQLException`. Why do we need to rethrow in our
>   open method? Is there a reason for this?

It's a matter of style to explicitly declare runtime exception like this to highlight that `open()` might fail. If you don't want to handle it, remove the throws clause.

> 2) What's the point of the whole constructor/open pair? Why not
>   initialize dbHelper and get a database ready for writing in the
>   constructor?

This allows you to create the instance (fast operation) without being forced to do the probably slow operation (disk IO, etc.) of opening the database; most of the  time this won't matter because you'll do both in one go as in your code snippet. Also, this keeps the constructor exception-free which some people prefer.

> 3) Why do we return the instance of the object in the open method
>   with return this? If the open method code were to be moved to the
>   constructor, we no would no longer need to return this, it would be
>   implicit, right? What am I missing here?

If it were moved into the constructor, then yes the `return this` would be implicit. As the usual way to use a DB helper class in Android is to create and open it in one go, `open()` just does some little builder pattern so you can go `TodoDbAdapter helper = new TodoDbAdapter(this).open();` for the most common use case.

To sum up: These three points of yours are mainly about style, there's little functional reason I can think of and definitely other ways to do it that are correct.

Comment: One last thing similar to question #1 which I forgot on the initial question. On that same tutorial, there are two methods to fetch notes, one fetches one row the other fetches all. They both use `.query()` which can throw `SQLException` but only one of them has the `throws` keyword. I assume it's an error on the author's part and that the justification for the throw is the same as #1?

Comment: Yes, seems like an oversight by the author.