# A few questions about SQLite database cursors in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor, android-loadermanager

To implement database access in my application I followed [Lars Vogel tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html), but I'm very confused about a couple of things...

1. Every time a call is made to `fetchTodo` a new cursor will be created and returned. Leaving the previous cursor for the garbage collector. So, if I don't use `startManagingCursor` or even the `CursorLoader` for that matter, should I call a `.close()` on the cursor when I'm done with it ? Outside of `fetchTodo` scope of course, example:

   Cursor cursor = mNotesAdapter.fetchTodo();
   // do something...
   cursor.close();

I'm done with this cursor and new one will be created on the next fetch, should I close it like this then or should I leave it for the garbage collector? Although I think I'm talking about 2 things entirely different... Point being, should I close it like in the example above or not?

2. `Cursor` also has a `.deactivate()` method and the documentation says it uses less resources (than active cursors). When exactly should I use this? For instance, in my app, I have a `ListActivity` which is populated through a `SimpleCursorAdapter` (the code initialization for this is only called once). The cursor being used is a class member variable, because I need it outside the method that populates the list. I need it to requery the database when something is deleted from it. But until a record is deleted, which is a user action and may take a while to happen, should I deactivate the cursor in the meantime? Cause it will be active again when I call `.requery()` again. Or the `SimpleCursorAdapter` is going to stop working because the cursor is not active?

**EDIT:** I just tested this one and found out that I can't call `deactivate()` after setting up the cursor adapter. The list will be empty if the cursor is not active, so it needs to remain active for as long as the ListActivity is displayed. In the end, we should just let `StartManagingCursor` handle it then. Or the new `CursorLoader`.

3. I know that `startManagingCursor`/`stopManagingCursor` are deprecated but I'm not targeting Honeycomb (at least for the time being) and I don't want to deal with the new `CursorLoader` for now. But in the tutorial above, `startManagingCursor` is used everywhere, but `stopManagingCursor` is never called once. Why not? Does Android deals with that in it's own way? Any situation I should call `stopManagingCursor`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: Updated answer to reflect updated question 1:

> 1) Every time a call is made to fetchTodo a new cursor will be created
>   and returned. Leaving the previous cursor for the garbage collector.
>   So, if I don't use startManagingCursor or even the CursorLoader for
>   that matter, should I call a .close() on the cursor when I'm done with
>   it ?

Yes, you should definitely either tell Android to `startManagingCursor()`, use `LoaderManager`/`CursorLoader` or `close()` it yourself. Not doing so will leak memory, the GC won't help with that as there's native resources behind the `Cursor` (e.g. file handles to the database).

> 2) Cursor also has a .deactive() method and the documentation says it
>   uses less resources (than active cursors). When exactly should I use
>   this? ...

**EDIT** to other readers: The OP found an answer and posted it in his question. The following still holds:

I've never used [`deactivate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#deactivate%28%29) (there's no `deactive()`), maybe someone else can explain this. If you want really painless requery/updates, do check out the `LoaderManager` framework -- it's not only for Honeycomb: using the compat library you can use `LoaderManager` (and `Fragments`) down to Android 1.6. Not only is it less code for you to write, but it completely offloads these things to Android, much more so than `startManagingCursor()`.

**EDIT2: Some notes on `LoaderManager`**

There are `LoaderManager` tutorials on developer.android.com but these are quite... complex and hard to understand the first time like most of the tutorials there. I also had to dig a lot, the best all-in-one stop I found so far is http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/ (plus all the javadocs and compat lib source you can find) --- the way `LoaderManager` works is very similar to the (now also deprecated, replaced by `DialogFragment`) managed dialogs with their `onCreateDialog`, `onPrepareDialog` methods where you just tell Android to "show dialog #123" and then Android calls your code with that ID; same for loaders: "load loader #123", Android calls on `onCreateLoader()`.

The only obvious drawback is initially, that `LoaderManager` relies heavily on the `ContentProvider` framework and some people seem to really dislike that. Sure, it's additional learning and code, but once you have a `ContentProvider` for your own data (even if only used privately in your app), all the data-to-view bindng is a breeze with `CursorLoader`. IMHO, there's little difference between rolling your own "content provider" and actually implementing the `ContentProvider` -- but this is just my highly controversial opinion :)

> 3) I know that startManagingCursor/stopManagingCursor are deprecated
>   but I'm not targeting Honeycomb (at least for the time being) and I
>   don't want to deal with the new CursorLoader for now. But in the
>   tutorial above, startManagingCursor is used everywhere, but
>   stopManagingCursor is never called once. Why not? Does Android deals
>   with that in it's own way? Any situation I should call
>   stopManagingCursor?

Once you call `startManagingCursor()` the `Cursor` is no longer your problem. Android will take care of closing the Cursor when your `Activity` gets destroyed (user navigates away, orientation change, ...). There's no need to match a call to `startManagingCursor()` with a call to `stopManagingCursor()` -- you usually don't want to take on the burden of managing a `Cursor` again once you've gotten rid of it.

Comment: #1 I totally misinterpreted my thoughts on that question, I'll need to rephrase it... #2 Yes, I meant `deactivate` (typo). I can't really find any good documentation on how to use the `LoaderManager`, not even here in SO questions. #3 I understand the point but if I'm not supposed to use `stopManagingCursor` if I made a call to `startManagingCursor`, why does that method even exists in the first place?

Comment: Also, just found the answer to #2; question edited once again with the answer.

Comment: Just got first daylight on my site of the globe, reading your edits now. Oh, just saw: Same side of the globe, just went to bed earlier than you did ;)

Comment: There you go, updated my answer, plus some personal notes on `LoaderManager`.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it :) Will take a look at the tutorial mentioned, maybe in the future I'll migrate to the `LoaderManager`.

Comment: The `LoaderManager` does not rely on the `ContentProvider` at all... it knows nothing about any of that. I think you meant to say is that the `CursorLoader` heavily relies on the `ContentProvider` (since the `CursorLoader`'s `startLoading` method contains a direct call to `getContentResolver().query(...)`).