# Android: AsyncQueryHandler and ContentProvider

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

So, I've looked around for quite a bit. But I didn't find a good guide or example.

I'm trying to implement an app with `SQLite DB` and I would like to use a threaded solution, but I'm not really sure how to get it done. I already implemented some `ContentProvider` for my db.

I need now to query the DB from my activity, but I don't know what is best practice. I was thinking about using the `AsyncQueryHandler`, sadly i didn't find a satisfying example.

Anyone can provide a tutorial or an example for `AsyncQueryHandler` OR is there another way to accomplish this?

*p.s.: I tried out `AsyncTask`, however I don't believe that this class is made for that purpose.*

Comment: If you already have a `ContentProvider`, you might want to check out `LoaderManager` and `CursorLoader` -- a tutorial about these I quite like is http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/

Comment: thanks, nice tutorial. By the way if you post it as answer I can accept it.

Comment: There you go, I had to pimp it a bit so I don't feel bad about getting a single link accepted ;)

Comment: AsyncQueryHandler is only useful for updating/inserting large amount of records into the db.  For reading-only use a CursorLoader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have a `ContentProvider`, you might want to check out `LoaderManager` and `CursorLoader`:

- a nice overview is given by
  http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#loader
- a tutorial about these I quite like is
  http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/
- an article on the Loaders framework in the Android Dev Guide:
  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html

Here's also a snippet from [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7603707/180740) on this topic:

> There are `LoaderManager` tutorials on developer.android.com but these are quite... complex and hard to understand the first time like most of the tutorials there. I also had to dig a lot, the best all-in-one stop I found so far is http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/ (plus all the javadocs and compat lib source you can find) --- the way `LoaderManager` works is very similar to the (now also deprecated, replaced by `DialogFragment`) managed dialogs with their `onCreateDialog`, `onPrepareDialog` methods where you just tell Android to "show dialog #123" and then Android calls your code with that ID; same for loaders: "load loader #123", Android calls on `onCreateLoader()`.

Comment: What if I have to use API level 10 features only? As far as I have seen this works since level 11. What would be the best approach in that case?

Comment: The Android Support Library provides LoaderManager, CursorLoader and a few more things all the way down to API level 4: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Using

Comment: `CursorLoader` is only used to load the cursor from the DB, What if you want to `Insert`, `Update`, or `Delete` something from the DB. You have to use `AsyncQueryHandler` for that purpose.